# How can i pass the items from a list as individual arguments to a function?

Tags: java

For Example

I have a list :

`List  <Example>  examp = new ArrayList();`

i want to pass the items in the list as arguments to a function

`public void Example(example1,example2,example3.......);`

where `example1` ,`example2` all are arraylist items

Comment: What utility does this provide over just passing the array? The only way to access all those parameters would be to use a list anyway (given how Java's method overloading works). What you are asking for tells me that you have a really questionable design.

Comment: pass all the list in "Example" function and in this function use examp.get(i)

Answer (score 1):

Q: How can i pass the items from a list as individual arguments to a function?

A:

```
List<Integer> exampleList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// Use this for a few specific items in the list
public void Example1(Integer arg1, Integer arg2, Integer argc);
...
Example1 (exampleList.get(0), exampleList.get(1), exampleList.get(2));

// Use this to pass many items (just pass the whole list)
public void Example2(List<Integer> args);
...
Example2 (exampleList);
```

Comment: This will not compile as primitive types can not be used as generics, only objects can.

Comment: @Polygnome - you're correct, of course :).  I edited the post.  The point I was trying to make is that "generics should be preferred over raw "Object".  Agreed?

Answer (score 0):

`examp .get(index)` to get element at index.

Example:

```
Example(examp .get(0), examp .get(1), examp .get(20)
```

Another methodology:

```
example(examp);
```

and your method signature should be

```
public void example(List<int> args);
```

List index starts at ZERO.

One suggestion: Java naming convention use small letter as first letter in method signature.

Comment: What if the list is huge and i need to pass them individually ??

Comment: Does your function have a ridiculous number of arguments, too?  (Either way, it looks like you should be reorganizing your code to avoid this problem in the first place.)

Comment: @kaushikpop: That is the exact question I have in my mind, does your function need to accept everything in list as paraemter? If you don't know ahead of time how many params you want to pass, passing list entire is best option that looking for each item.

Comment: Better pass the list as argument then process it to take the corresponding elements

Answer (score 0):

You could define the method with varargs:

```
void exampleMethod(Example... example) {
  // ...
}
```

and pass them like that:

```
exampleMethod(examp.get(0), examp.get(1), examp.get(6);  // individual examples
exampleMethod(examp.toArray(new Example[]{}));           // all examples at once
```

But I see no significant advantage compared to passing the list directly...